# How do I use Split on a named range?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to look through formulas in a range of cells and match up named ranges in the worksheet to any named ranges in the formula and replace the named ranges with their reference cells.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim workrng As Range
Dim xname As Name
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim arr_string as String

Set workrng = Application.Selection
Set workrng = Application.InputBox("txt", "header txt", workrng.Address, Type:=8
Set workrng = workrng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

For Each rng In workrng
    For Each xname in ThisWorkbook.names
        arr = Split(xname.Name, "!")
        arr_string = arr(1)
        Debug.Print arr_string
        If InStr(rng.Formula, xname.Name) > 0 Then
            rng.Formula = VBA.Replace(rng.Formula, xname.Name, VBA.Replace(xname.RefersTo, "=", ""))
        End If
    Next
Next
```

When I debug print "xname.Name" I get results that include the sheet name. For example: Specifications!_MyNamedRange. However, the formula in the cell only says: _MyNamedRange. That's why I'm trying to split it. However, when I debug my array, there is nothing in it.

Comment: Hard without data.  But the sheet name usually goes with the `.RefersTo` property.

Comment: I think we need a bit more explanation of what you actually want to happen here. Because if you're just replacing the named range's name within the formula, [the code you use](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/652-excel-replace-range-names.html) should be working just fine. The fact that you try to pull the absolute cell reference (eg `$A$1:$B$2`) out of the named range confuses me regarding what you actually want to accomplish

Comment: @RonRosenfeld correct. But for some reason when I debug xname.Name it returns the named range with the sheet name (ie, Specifications!_MyRangedName) rather than just the named range itself.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 The code I was using does work on other workbooks. For some reason it is behaving differently here. I'm pulling the absolute cell reference because I want to replace the named ranges in formulas for specific cells because I'm deleting out those named ranges from the workbook and before I do so, I want to fix the formulas so I don't end up with #NAME? errors.

Comment: Since the problem exists on one specific workbook, the easiest method to figure this out would be to examine the workbook itself.  If you can upload a copy of one that demonstrates the problem (and edit your question to include a link), someone should be able to help you.  I will be away for a few days and, if you haven't received an answer, will check back Wed or Thu

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know exactly what to do without a worksheet.  But a couple of changes you need to make:

```
Dim arr() As Variant --> Dim arr As Variant

arr = Split(xname.Name, "!") --> arr = Split(xname.RefersTo, "!")
```